# Check if an array is empty hence disable a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Am trying to disable a button if an array isemty but fails

```
<button [disabled]="(users.length ==0 )?true:false">Send mass emails</button>
```

IN the ts file

```
users: UsersModel[];
```

THe above throws an error

```
Bindings cannot contain assignments at column
```

How do i disable that button if the array is emty

Comment: Not sure about angular2, but I guess angular1 had `ng-enable`. angular2 also must have something similar. Also just a POV, but its always better to use functions instead of inline expression. This way, you will keep your view clean and code more modular

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you initialized the `users: UsersModel[]` array in your component so it's coming back as `undefined` and you are trying to access `length` property of an undefined object/array. Try the following to disable the button if `users` array has NOT been initialized or the length is equal to 0:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!users || users.length === 0">Send Mass Emails</button>
```

Here is [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tU4ByfSnnhYUo0gOSBiA?p=preview) demonstrating this in action.

What you could also consider is initializing the `user` array to an empty array in your component:

```
users: UsersModel[] = [];
```

Then you could simply do to disable/enable the button based on users length being zero/falsy:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!user.length">Send mass emails</button>
```

Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/nnPwJYPWuBr5i24yB0Ei?p=preview) demonstrating initializing the `users` array to an empty array and checking length to disable button accordingly.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button [disabled]="users.length===0?true:false">Send mass emails</button>
```

You can add you condition to the disabled tag like the following. even you can check for the users array then check the length like

```
<button [disabled]="!user || users.length===0?true:false">Send mass emails</button>
```

Comment: Missing explanation. -1. Answers without explanation are incomplete. Please post answers explaining **What and Why** your solution solves

Comment: @Rajesh its was pretty self explanatory

Comment: To you and me, yes. But SO is a place for everyone. You are answering for readers and you cannot be sure of readers' level. Hence explanation.